# Multi-Dimensional array null issue

Tags: java, arrays, list, null

Okay so this will be a program that list students names and their test scores. I have it all figured out but one little thing. I have to lines that list the name of the student...then allows me to add another student to the list without the exact same name repeating. (see lines labelled 1 and 2)

line one collects the names from firstNameField and lastNameField which the teacher would input...and the second line would "go up one" for the array, to ensure the names don't repeat when another student is added.

Unfortunately...everytime another student is added it looks a little somethnig like this...

EXAMPLE:

Jane Doenull 65 76 45 89 Jane Doenull 65 87 45 76 
John Smithnull 65 76 45 89

You can clearly see the problem...."null" is there, plus is repeats the second name (Jane Doe)

So what should I do to prevent this?

public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {

```
int [][] aryStudent = new int [15][4]; //number of student (15) test scores (4 scores)
String[][] aryNames = new String[15][2]; //lists the names of students
int numOfStudents = 0; //starts off students from zero...
int marks = 0; 

int test1;
int test2;
int test3;
int test4;

public StudentGradesView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
```

//GUI stuff...

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String currentList = studentListField.getText();

    //Collects integers from test1Field though test4Field
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
    aryStudent[numOfStudents][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    for (int x=0; x <= numOfStudents && x<15; x++) {
        sb.append(firstNameField.getText()).append(" ").append(lastNameField.getText()); //(1)
        sb.append(aryNames[x][0]); //(2)
        for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {
            sb.append(" ").append(aryStudent[x][y]);
            studentListField.setText(sb.toString() + "\n" + currentList);
        }
        sb.append("\n");

    }
    numOfStudents ++;
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: use an iterator (for loop) for filling aryStudent[numOfStudents[loopIterator]]

Comment: It seems to me like what you are calling line1 and line2 is appeding the first name of the student twice.

Comment: Your code is crying for objects. Instead of storing information in parallel arrays, use a single array of Student objects, each Student having a firstName, lastName, score1, score2, score3 and score4 atributes. Java is an OO language. Use objects.